# Is it good idea to use git system as a part of application?

Tags: git, performance, architecture, gitlab

I'm building an application similar to WiX or one&one. I have users, each user has settings of site in XML. Now I'm thinking on creating GIT repository ( it would be cool to see a history of changes, and for example using git enable me to detect conflicts when for example there are 2 admins and they're both make changes in same time ) for that settings. So every time when the user changes something in settings of site I make commit, of course to make that git oprations I'll use some service. Now I'm wondering how looks like performance of GIT server, would't be a problem for GIT to handle for example 10 commits per second ? And second question how looks like performance of GIT client, I need to perform action like commit and checkout ( for each user I plan to make new branch )

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to find a solution at the wrong level of abstraction.

The important concept is the configuration and how it evolved over time, not how it's storage representation evolved over time.

Imagine that configuration would eventually be stored in a relationnal DB, what would you do then?

The correct approach here is one that works off a standardized configuration representation (in memory) that is entirely decoupled from the storage mechanism. With such representation you could still keep an history of what changed over time and detect conflicts.

Comment: I plan to store latest version of settings in DB. GIT would be for history purposes and tool for detecting conflicts

Comment: What I am saying is that you should model the history of changes into the DB as well and detect conflicts simply by comparing the values and using optimistic concurrency. There is not point in tracking XML text changes, it will not bring you any benefits and will limit the flexibility of your system.